# cant install ruby with rvm no-same-user error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to use rvm to install ruby 1.8.7 and I get the following error:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p334 to /Users/vincent/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p334
ERROR: Error running 'bunzip2 < '/Users/vincent/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /Users/vincent/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_50863', please read /Users/vincent/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p334/extract.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to extract the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

This is the log:

```
[2011-04-27 14:26:21] bunzip2 < '/Users/vincent/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /Users/vincent/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_49627
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '--no-same-owner': No such file or directory
[2011-04-27 14:34:53] bunzip2 < '/Users/vincent/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /Users/vincent/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_50007
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '--no-same-owner': No such file or directory
[2011-04-27 14:41:20] bunzip2 < '/Users/vincent/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /Users/vincent/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_50572
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '--no-same-owner': No such file or directory
[2011-04-27 14:45:38] bunzip2 < '/Users/vincent/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2' | tar xf --no-same-owner - -C /Users/vincent/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_50863
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '--no-same-owner': No such file or directory
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bug in rvm, see latest commit https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/52018750763d5321b7b993e201c8589b98e090f9

Comment: Thank you. I installed using this And rvm is installed but give the error described above:  How do I use the latest commit to get rid of my error. sorry if this is noob extreme